# How to make "poor man's roaming" by proxying cell calls to SIP or Skype?

Tags: skype, proxy, sip, roaming

What applications should I use to make the Android device to forward calls from cell network to SIP or Skype and back?

One device ("Home") is expected to be left at home, serving as proxy; other device ("Travel") is just using data connection to connect to the first device, so it works like this:

1. Someone is calling you using cell network.
2. Home device receives the call and calls Travel using SIP.
3. Travel device sees the incoming SIP call.
4. You answer the call.
5. Home device is proxying between SIP and cell network for you until you drop the call.

How to do it? How to workaround greedy cell providers?

Answer (score 1):

There is an opensource application Sipdroid, which theoretically could be modified to do proxying. But, judging from the poor general Android SIP experience, I'd think it would be very unreliable solution.

Easier way to workaround greedy cell providers seems to set up an IP PBX on the home computer, or get a free account at freepbxes.org and get a cheap SIP-connected phone number to eventually route your calls thru while using your "Travel" device's SIP connection to terminate calls.

Comment: http://freepbxes.org fail to reply. Also I don't sure it will be available in my country (where state telecom monopolist protects itself with lawsuits against VoIP).

Comment: Oh, I see. I've got a few friends in Belarus, and telephony communications with them is the most difficult amongst all I'm calling nationally and internationally. Well, looks like Android won't do for this. Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4723453/android-as-sip-to-gsm-gateway So your solution seems to be a computer-based PBX, e.g. Asterisk, with a cheap GSM voice-capable modem - that will be able to forward calls via SIP to your "Travel" handset.

Comment: Can I use Android itself as voice-capable modem? For example, what will happen if I call with GSM and CSipSimple simultaneously (will it de-facto route the sound)?

Comment: I'm afraid CSipSimple (or any other user-level app for that matter) doesn't have access to GSM audio. Someone more knowledgeable should confirm if this is the case.

Comment: CallRecorder applications does record calls, for example; and it even does not require the root access AFAIR. Also just recording from microphone should have some effect (poor quality although).

Comment: Can I setup IP PBX with GSM connection ?